# Static function and access to the class variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

I've got a class `MainWindow` that contain a static function `lancerServeur()` ( this function is static because I use it in a thread ), now I want to call a private variable `bool_Serveur_Fonctionne` in this function, here's the code :

```
void MainWindow::lancerServeur(){
    serveur s;
    while(bool_Serveur_Fonctionne){
        s.receiveDataUDP();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't, after some research it seems like a static function can't have access to what is not static, so what do I do to permit my function to access to : `bool_Serveur_Fonctionne` ? And could you give more information about this, what if I want to change this variable in `static function` and `non-static function` ?

Here's the error : `invalid use of member 'MainWindow::bool_Serveur_Fonctionne' in static member function bool bool_Serveur_Fonctionne;`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you pass a parameter in to the function? If so you'll have to manually pass in the object.

Comment: I can't pass the parameter, how do I do it manually ?

Comment: Depends on the threading API. Windows and pthread let you pass a void pointer to the thread creation function which is then passed to the function.

Comment: I'm using the std::thread

Comment: You'll need to pass an instance of this class to the thread function to make it available there. Also you would probably need a synchronization mechanism (e.g. a mutex), to protect accessing the variable from concurrent access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass it as parameter to thread function:

```
void MainWindow::lancerServeur(MainWindow& obj){
    serveur s;
    // IF bool_Serveur_Fonctionne is public otherwise use some function to 
    //return value of this
    while(obj.bool_Serveur_Fonctionne){
        s.receiveDataUDP();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    MainWindow m; 
    std::thread t(MainWindow::lancerServeur, std::ref(m));
    t.join();  
}
```

**EDIT:**

Updated the code as @Casey has suggested.

Comment: do the variable 'a' will be shared between my main and my thread ?

Comment: Yes, since you are passing instance of your class, you can access it like you do in normal methods.

Comment: Are you sure ? Because don't work with me, I pass to my thread bool_Server_Fonctionne , and when I put it to false in my main, it's still true in my thread, you are sure the variable is shared between them ?

Comment: It also depends upon execution order of both thread. It may happen that you are setting it in main thread false after child thread has executed that line. try make that variable **volatile** and join statement to control thread execution order and variable sharing.

Comment: Never heard about that, how do I do that ... Sorry for my stupidity :(

Comment: `volatile bool bool_Serveur_Fonctionne;` just the way you use any other type qualifier in c++. This keyword tells compiler not to optimize this variable and also share same copy across all thread. If you will not use `volatile` each thread makes its own copy of variable.

Comment: @dream_machine Note that `volatile` is in no way a protection from race conditions! You should advise to protect concurrent access with e.g. a mutex (as I did in my comment on the question). _'each thread makes its own copy of variable.'_ and this is simply wrong rubbish :-/ ...

Comment: The `std::thread` constructor copies its arguments: this program invokes `lancerServeur` on a *copy* of `m`, which is probably not what the OP wants. Use `void MainWindow::lancerServeur(MainWindow& obj);` and `std::thread t(MainWindow::lancerServeur, std::ref(m));` instead.

Answer (score 3):

static functions can only access static members of a class, they **don't have access to** `this` pointer. If you think about it, a static method is not attached to any instance of an object, so it makes no sense to try to access a non-static member (you would need an instance of an object to do that).

You have three choices :

1) Make `bool_Serveur_Fonctionne` a static member of the class.

2) Pass an instance of an object (`MainWindow`) with an accessor to`bool_Serveur_Fonctionne` to your static method.

3) Pass a reference of `bool_Serveur_Fonctionne` as a parameter of your static method.

**Note:**

Consider `std::atomic<bool>` as the type for your `bool_Serveur_Fonctionne`

Answer (score 2):

> this function is static because I use it in a thread

You can start a thread with a non-static member function :

```
std::thread(&MainWindow::lancerServeur, mainWindowInstance);
```